# SQL SORT BY DATENAME does not work

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My query is

```
USE MyDB

SELECT DATENAME(DD, s.requestdate)
FROM   sample_table s
WHERE  MONTH(s.requestdate) = 12
GROUP  BY DATENAME(DD, s.requestdate)
ORDER  BY DATENAME(DD, s.requestdate) DESC
```

The output I expect is to be ordered by day of month in descending order but my output is ordered such

```
9
8
 7....till 1 then 19, 18...till 11
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`DATENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174395.aspx) returns a string.

Use [`DATEPART(DD,s.requestdate)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) instead as that returns an integer and will sort as you expect.